# $Hom_G(\pi,\sigma)$ = $Hom_{\mathfrak{g}}(d\pi,d\sigma)$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the corresponding Lie algebra. Let $(\pi,V)$ and $(\sigma, W)$ be representations of $G$, with corresponding differentials $d\pi$ and $d\sigma$, which are $\mathfrak{g}$ representations. I want to know about the relationship between $Hom_G(\pi,\sigma)$ and $Hom_{\mathfrak{g}}(d\pi,d\sigma)$. Are they equal? Any help or reference is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the $G$-module $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb R}(V,W)$, we have $\text{Hom}_G(V,W)=\text{Hom}_{\mathbb R}(V,W)^G$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathfrak g}(V,W) = \text{Hom}_{\mathbb R}(V,W)^{\mathfrak g}$, so it suffices to study the relation between $V^G$ and $V^{\mathfrak g}$ for a $G$-module $V$ (and that this also special case of your formulation when taking $V$ to be the trivial $G$-module). Now show that for any $v\in V$, the closed subgroup $\text{Stab}_G(v) := \{g\in G\ |\ g.v=v\}$ has Lie algebra $\text{Lie}(\text{Stab}_G(v))=\text{stab}_{\mathfrak g}(v) := \{X\in{\mathfrak g}\ |\ X.v = 0\}$, and use that for a *connected* Lie group $G$ and a closed subgroup $H\subseteq G$ we have $H=G$ if and only if $\text{Lie}(H) = \text{Lie}(G)$.

For $G$ not connected, you only have the inclusion $V^G \subset V^{\mathfrak g}$, and the other inclusion is false in general as you can see by looking at the case where $G$ is finite.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. BTW, I don't want to pick specifically on you, as nearly everyone here seems to do this, but why did you bother to answer this question without upvoting it (I am, at the moment, the only upvoter for both the answer and the question)?

Comment: @Stephen: I'm sorry, I just forgot, nothing deep behind it. I gave it an upvote now.

Comment: No worries! It's a phenomenon that puzzles me. It happens with such frequency (see an example that happened as we were having this exchange here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993682/how-to-express-z8-%E2%88%92-1-as-the-product-of-two-linear-factors-and-three-quadrati) that I finally asked you why just now.