# How to express $z^8 − 1$ as the product of two linear factors and three quadratic factors

Tags: complex-analysis

> Verify
>
> $$(z-e^{i \theta} ) (z - e^{-i \theta} ) ≡ z^2 - 2\cos \theta + 1$$
>
> Hence express $z^8 − 1$ as the product of two linear factors and three quadratic factors, where all
> coefficients are real and expressed in a non-trigonometric form.

---

For the first part I just expanded  the LHS and showed its equal to RHS.

**Roots** of $z^8-1$:

$$z= e^{i \frac{\pi k}{4}}$$

> Where $k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$

Ok since they want non-Trignometric so :

I know two roots, which are obvious:

$$z=1,-1$$

$$z^8-1=(z-1)(z+1)(z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)$$

They want two linear factors which I believe I have found: $(z+1)$ and $(z-1)$

How do I make

$$(z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)$$

to three quadratic factors? And they mentioned **Hence** , so **I have to use the identity I verified**. Please help.

Comment: Do you know the eight roots of $z^8 - 1$?

Comment: @TheArtist, We can set $k=0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,4$ to utilize the formula

Comment: @Hurkyl I have mentioned the roots on the question :)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee oh so I have to jus find the roots and multiply two pairs with each other to form the three quadratic equations???

Comment: @TheArtist Fortunately, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z^8-1=(z^2-1)(z^6+z^4+z^2+1)=(z-1)(z+1)(z^2+1)(z^4+1)$$
$$z^4+1=(z^2+1)^2-2z^2=(z^2+\sqrt2 z+1)(z^2-\sqrt2 z+1)$$

Comment: There is no factor $z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1$.

Comment: I like this answer. I will have to remember that trick to factor $z^4+1$.

Comment: How did you factorize $(z^6+z^4+z^2+1)$ so quickly? :o I don't even know how to do even by hours :o Can you please tell me how you did that ? :) Thanks

Comment: @TheArtist, it's easier to see it if you write $z^8-1=(z^4-1)(z^4+1)=(z^2-1)(z^2+1)(z^4+1)$.

Comment: Maybe $x^3+x^2+x+1$ is easier to decipher?

Comment: Got it @Stephen :D Yes understood Did thank you very much :)

Comment: I forgot to add the (+1) , this answer :D I also learned the trick of factorizing $(z^4+1)$ from this ;) I hope it stays in my head for long :p

Answer (score 1):

Recall the two versions of the fundamental theorem of algebra:

- Any complex polynomial can be factored into a product of linear terms
- Any real polynomial can be factored into a product of linear and quadratic terms (and the quadratic terms have no real roots)

In this case, we can find the factorization as a complex polynomial into linear terms easily; the trick then to recover the factorization as a real polynomial is to multiply the linear terms together appropriately to convert pairs of complex linear terms into real quadratic terms.

In particular, you want to group the conjugate roots together, and multiply them as described by the identity you list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method which make use of your identity.

$$z^8-1=(z-1)(z+1)(z^2+1)(z^4+1)$$

\begin{align*}
(z^4+1)&=(z^2+i)(z^2-i)\\
&=(z^2-e^{i-\frac{\pi}{2}})(z^2-e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})\\&=(z+e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})(z-e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})(z+e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})(z-e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})\\&=(z-e^{-i\frac{5\pi}{4}})(z-e^{i\frac{5\pi}{4}})(z-e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})(z-e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})\end{align*}

Then use your formula, you get $$z^4+1=(z^2+\sqrt2 z+1)(z^2-\sqrt2 z+1)$$